# Itô integral probability distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I know in general this must not have an analytical expression in terms of common functions, but how do you (at least in theory) get the probability distribution of $X_t$ for a given $t$ in the integral

$$
X_t = \int_0^t f(t)\, \mathbb{d}W_t
$$

Comment: If $f$ is deterministic then $X_t$ is a centered normal random variable with variance $$E(X_t^2)=\int_0^tf(s)^2\,ds.$$

Comment: @gerd : Those stochastic integrals are known under the denomination of "Wiener Integrals". Best regards.

Comment: @Did can you add this with some reference so that I can accept your answer? Also, what if $f(s)$ is some stochastic process with known distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Did has commented, if $f(s)$ is deterministic, then $X_t$ will be a centered normal random variable with variance
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_t^2) = \int^t_0 f(s)^2 \,\mathbb{d}s
$$

For references, see [this](https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Andreas_Eberle/StoAn1112/StochasticAnalysisFinal.pdf), pg 113.